# Java: Assigning Non Static Variable to Static Variable

Tags: java, variables, scope

I'm using a class called `GlobalVar` to store some global variables required for the entire application. The class looks something like this:

```
public class GlobalVar {

    MyProps props = new MyProps();

    public GlobalVar() throws Exception
    {

    }

    public static String PPFirstName = "Kim";
    public static String PPLastName = "Smith";


    String zip = props.Props.getIPZip("IPZip");
    public static String IPZip = zip;

}
```

However, in the last two lines I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot assign non static variable to static variable.
```

I understand the source of the problem (as `zip` is non static and `IPZip` is static) my question is: Is there any way around this? I.e, any way to assign the value set in `"Props"` to `"IPZip"` static var?

Note: The purpose of using this method is that I am able to use the syntax `GlobalVar.IPZip` anywhere in the application..

Comment: This is likely a design issue. Have you looked into using other methods of global variable persistence? Could you transform your `GlobalVar` class into a POJO with getters and setters? Maybe use a Singleton pattern if you're worried about multiple class copies being used

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance of `MyProps`, then calling its non-static `getIPZip` method. You cannot assign the result of a non-static method to a static variable.

Instead, you would need to convert the `getIPZip` method to be a static method of your `MyProps` class, then you could assign its result to yor `IPZip` variable like this.

```
public static String IPZip = MyProps.getIPZip("IPZip");
```

Then you could access `IPZip` anywhere using `GlobalVar.IPZip`.

However, if you make the `getIPZip` method static, adding another variable to the `GlobalVar` class is somewhat unnecessary, as you could just call `MyProps.getIPZip("IPZip");` anywhere in your code.

Another option would be to move the `getIPZip` method into your `GlobalVar` class and make it a static method in there, then you could call `GlobalVar.getIPZip("IPZip");`.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand fully, but why can't you do this?

```
public static String IPZip = props.Props.getIPZip("IPZip");
```

Instead of assigning something later?